# Example of stabsel with glmnet

Tags: r

The question is about the *fitfun* parameter of the function *stabsel* in the *stabs* R package.

I need to perform stability selection on lasso logistic models whit R.
The package *stabs* has a good example to perform stability selection using the *lars* package.

I report here the example that can be found on the *stabs* github page https://github.com/hofnerb/stabs

```
library("stabs")
library("lars")
## make data set available
data("bodyfat", package = "TH.data")
## set seed
set.seed(1234)

## lasso
(stab.lasso <- stabsel(x = bodyfat[, -2], y = bodyfat[,2],
                       fitfun = lars.lasso, cutoff = 0.75,
                       PFER = 1))

## stepwise selection
(stab.stepwise <- stabsel(x = bodyfat[, -2], y = bodyfat[,2],
                          fitfun = lars.stepwise, cutoff = 0.75,
                          PFER = 1))

## plot results
par(mfrow = c(2, 1))
plot(stab.lasso, main = "Lasso")
plot(stab.stepwise, main = "Stepwise Selection")
```

Can you provide a similar example in which *stabs* is applied on *glmnet* and not *lars*?

I have a script that use *glmnet* to fit lasso logistic models. I would like to maintain the script as is and implement ot top of that the *stabsel*, I do not want to change the script to use *lars* instead of *gmlnet*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, this is documented (though, admittedly no example is given). The only thing you need to do is to replace the `fitfun` (see `?fitfun` for further functions):

```
(stab.glmnet <- stabsel(x = bodyfat[, -2], y = bodyfat[,2],
                        fitfun = glmnet.lasso, cutoff = 0.75,
                        PFER = 1))
par(mfrow = c(2, 1))
plot(stab.glmnet, main = "Lasso (glmnet)")
## plot lars solution for comparison
if (exists("stab.lasso"))
    plot(stab.lasso, main = "Lasso")
```

I'll add an example as requested to make it even easier.

Comment: @mox: The issue has been resolved in commit [b147e78](https://github.com/hofnerb/stabs/commit/b147e782a96e61c8e08e24d11630109a6c724dde)